# Jest - mocked setTimeout not called second time

Tags: node.js, async-await, jestjs, settimeout

This is the exact test and code I am running

```
let interval = 5
const promise = () => {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
        resolve()
    })
}
const init = async () => {
    await promise()
    interval *= 2;
    console.log("=> setTimeout", interval);
    setTimeout(init, interval);
};

jest.useFakeTimers();
jest.spyOn(global, 'setTimeout');

describe("setTimeout", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.resetAllMocks();
    });

    it("should call setTimeout 2 times", async () => {
        await init();

        expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        jest.runOnlyPendingTimers();
        expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
    })
});
```

The problem is that, according to jest setTimeout is called only once, but the console.log clearly proves it is called twice. If init function is not async and remove await promise(), all works as expected.
Is this some Jest edge case or I am missing something?

Here is the working synchronous code:

```
let interval = 5

const init = () => {
    interval *= 2;
    console.log("=> setTimeout", interval);
    setTimeout(init, interval);
};

jest.useFakeTimers();
jest.spyOn(global, 'setTimeout');

describe("PulpoService", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.resetAllMocks();
    });

    it("should call setTimeout 2 times", () => {
        init();

        expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        jest.runOnlyPendingTimers();
        expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
    })
});
```